# Creating variable arrays with Javascript (dyamic, drop down)

Tags: javascript, arrays, menu

I've been searching the board for a while (both here and Google) and can't seem to find what I'm looking. (Sorry if I've missed it and this qualifies as an annoying/redundant question.)

I'm working on form that will have copious amounts of drop downs based on previous selected variable(s). I was trying to come up with an easier way than having to create the individual fields and then hide/show based on selection. Ultimately, I'm aiming for a "tree" with between 3-5 levels of menus. (Clients doing, not mine.)

What the Logic looks like:

Variables: type, offer1, offer2, insert1, insert2, insert3,...

Where [type] determines [offer1,2] which has up to 3 variables each [insert1,2,3...]

So If user selects Type A: Offer1 = Array A (Insert1 = ArrayA1, Insert2 = ArrayA2, Insert3 = null) and Offer2 = Array B (Insert4 = ArrayB4, Insert5 = null); and so on and so forth.

So far, everything I've found only seems to handle the first tier, and JS isn't exactly my forte. Any pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please add your solution thus far (code), and point out where you're having trouble.

Comment: see your tag please, is it surely _java_ or _javascript_?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like [this](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/tripleMenu.htm) or [this](http://www.coursesweb.net/javascript/multiple-select-dropdown-list-javascript_t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else runs across this issue, I found this solution that uses JQuery: 
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained